Удалить путь из $path
Подскажите как удалить ненужный путь в переменной $PATH?
Например после перехода на python 3.13 у меня в path осталась ссылка на 3.12 (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin), как ее удалить? Она никак не мешает, просто режет глаз)

Вам надо найти, где этот путь добавляется в $PATH, и удалить его. Других способов нету.
В зависимости от shell, это может быть или .bash_profile или .zshrc (zsh в macos по умолчанию) в домашнем каталоге. Если не нашли, где идет добавление, пробегитесь grep-ом по всему домашнему каталогу:
$ grep -R "Versions/3.12" ~/

